# Getting a snapshot from a webcam with Delphi

Tags: delphi, callback, webcam, video-capture, vfw

I need to get a regular snapshot from a webcam in Delphi.  Speed is not a problem (once a second is fine).  I have tried demo code from based on stuff from [http://delphi.pjh2.de](http://delphi.pjh2.de/) but I can't get it to work.  It compiles and runs OK but the callback function never fires.

I don't have a real webcam but am running instead a simulator.  The simulator works (I can see the video using Skype) but not with the test app.  I don't really know where to start looking...

Can anyone be bothered to try this code? (Apologies for the voluminous post - couldn't find how or if you can attach files - a zip file is available [here](http://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bz3Kt0tCTCQ3YzYzOWVlNjctYTk5Zi00MmVjLTgxNWEtMTMyMTA3YWUzODU1&export=download&hl=en).)

Alternatively, any webcam demo code would be appreciated, preferably with a known good EXE as well as source.

```
program WebCamTest;

uses
  Forms,
  WebCamMainForm in 'WebCamMainForm.pas' {Form1},
  yuvconverts in 'yuvconverts.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.


unit WebCamMainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, YUVConverts, StdCtrls, JPeg {, TntStdCtrls} ;

const
  WM_CAP_START = WM_USER;
  WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT       = WM_CAP_START+ 10;

  WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW          = WM_CAP_START+ 50;
  WM_CAP_SET_OVERLAY          = WM_CAP_START+ 51;
  WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE      = WM_CAP_START+ 52;

  WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOP    = WM_CAP_START+ 61;
  WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME   = WM_CAP_START+ 5;
  WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT      = WM_CAP_START+ 44;

  WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT      = WM_CAP_START+ 41;

  PICWIDTH= 640;
  PICHEIGHT= 480;
  SUBLINEHEIGHT= 18;
  EXTRAHEIGHT= 400;

type
  TVIDEOHDR= record
    lpData: Pointer; // address of video buffer
    dwBufferLength: DWord; // size, in bytes, of the Data buffer
    dwBytesUsed: DWord; // see below
    dwTimeCaptured: DWord; // see below
    dwUser: DWord; // user-specific data
    dwFlags: DWord; // see below
    dwReserved1, dwReserved2, dwReserved3: DWord; // reserved; do not use
  end;
  TVIDEOHDRPtr= ^TVideoHDR;

  DWordDim= array[1..PICWIDTH] of DWord;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCapHandle: THandle;
    FCodec: TVideoCodec;
    FBuf1, FBuf2: array[1..PICHEIGHT] of DWordDim;
    FBitmap: TBitmap;
    FJpeg: TJPegImage;
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


function capCreateCaptureWindow(lpszWindowName: LPCSTR;
  dwStyle: DWORD;
  x, y,
  nWidth,
  nHeight: integer;
  hwndParent: HWND;
  nID: integer): HWND; stdcall;
  external 'AVICAP32.DLL' name 'capCreateCaptureWindowA';


function FrameCallbackFunction(AHandle: hWnd; VIDEOHDR: TVideoHDRPtr): bool; stdcall;
var
  I: integer;
begin
  result:= true;

  with form1 do begin
  try
    ConvertCodecToRGB(FCodec, VideoHDR^.lpData, @FBuf2, PICWIDTH, PICHEIGHT);

    for I:= 1 to PICHEIGHT do FBuf1[I]:= FBuf2[PICHEIGHT- (I- 1)];
    SetBitmapBits(FBitmap.Handle, PICWIDTH* PICHEIGHT* SizeOf(DWord), @FBuf1);

    FBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clWhite;
    FBitmap.Canvas.Font.Color:= clRed;

    FJpeg.Assign(FBitmap);

    FJpeg.CompressionQuality:= 85;
    FJpeg.ProgressiveEncoding:= true;
    FJpeg.SaveToFile('c:\webcam.jpg');

    SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME, 0, 0);
  except
  end;
  end;
end;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var  BitmapInfo: TBitmapInfo;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;

  FBitmap:= TBitmap.Create;
  FBitmap.Width:= PICWIDTH;
  FBitmap.Height:= PICHEIGHT+ SUBLINEHEIGHT+ EXTRAHEIGHT;
  FBitmap.PixelFormat:= pf32Bit;
  FBitmap.Canvas.Font.Assign(Panel1.Font);
  FBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bssolid;
  FBitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(0, PICHEIGHT, PICWIDTH, PICHEIGHT+ SUBLINEHEIGHT);

  FJpeg:= TJpegImage.Create;

  FCapHandle:= capCreateCaptureWindow('Video', WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, PICWIDTH, PICHEIGHT, Panel1.Handle, 1);
  SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 15000, 0);
  sendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_OVERLAY, 1, 0);
  SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, 1, 0);

  // SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT,1,0);     // -this was commented out

  FillChar(BitmapInfo, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), 0);
  SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), Integer(@BitmapInfo));
  FCodec:= BICompressionToVideoCodec(bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biCompression);
  if FCodec<> vcUnknown then begin
    Timer1.Enabled:= true;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
  FJpeg.Free;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FCodec= vcUnknown then
    showMessage('unknown compression');
  FBitmap.Height:= PICHEIGHT+ SUBLINEHEIGHT;
end;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME, 0, integer(@FrameCallbackFunction));
  SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOP, 1, 0); // ist hintergrundlauff盲hig
end;

end.

object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 301
  ClientWidth = 562
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnActivate = FormActivate
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 48
    Top = 16
    Width = 185
    Height = 145
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 464
    Top = 24
  end
end

{**************************************************************************************************}
{                                                                                                  }
{  YUVConverts                                                                                     }
{                                                                                                  }
{  The contents of this file are subject to the Y Library Public License Version 1.0 (the          }
{  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a   }
{  copy of the License at http://delphi.pjh2.de/                                                   }
{                                                                                                  }
{  Software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF  }
{  ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing        }
{  rights and limitations under the License.                                                       }
{                                                                                                  }
{  The Original Code is: YUVConverts.pas, part of CapDemoC.dpr.                                    }
{  The Initial Developer of the Original Code is Peter J. Haas (libs@pjh2.de). Portions created    }
{  by Peter J. Haas are Copyright (C) 2000-2005 Peter J. Haas. All Rights Reserved.                }
{                                                                                                  }
{  Contributor(s):                                                                                 }
{                                                                                                  }
{  You may retrieve the latest version of this file at the homepage of Peter J. Haas, located at   }
{  http://delphi.pjh2.de/                                                                          }
{                                                                                                  }
{**************************************************************************************************}

// For history see end of file

{$ALIGN ON, $BOOLEVAL OFF, $LONGSTRINGS ON, $IOCHECKS ON, $WRITEABLECONST OFF, $OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}
{$RANGECHECKS OFF, $TYPEDADDRESS ON, $MINENUMSIZE 1}

unit yuvconverts;

interface
uses
  Windows;

type
  TVideoCodec = (vcUnknown, vcRGB, vcYUY2, vcUYVY, vcBTYUV, vcYVU9, vcYUV12, vcY8, vcY211);

const
  BI_YUY2  = $32595559;  // 'YUY2'
  BI_UYVY  = $59565955;  // 'UYVY'
  BI_BTYUV = $50313459;  // 'Y41P'
  BI_YVU9  = $39555659;  // 'YVU9'  planar
  BI_YUV12 = $30323449;  // 'I420'  planar
  BI_Y8    = $20203859;  // 'Y8  '
  BI_Y211  = $31313259;  // 'Y211'

function BICompressionToVideoCodec(Value: DWord): TVideoCodec;

function ConvertCodecToRGB(Codec: TVideoCodec; Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer): Boolean;

implementation

function BICompressionToVideoCodec(Value: DWord): TVideoCodec;
begin
  case Value of
    BI_RGB, BI_BITFIELDS: Result := vcRGB;   // no RLE
    BI_YUY2:              Result := vcYUY2 ;
    BI_UYVY:              Result := vcUYVY ;
    BI_BTYUV:             Result := vcBTYUV;
    BI_YVU9:              Result := vcYVU9;
    BI_YUV12:             Result := vcYUV12;
    BI_Y8:                Result := vcY8;
    BI_Y211:              Result := vcY211;
  else
    Result := vcUnknown;
  end;
end;

const
  // RGB255 ColorFAQ
  fY  =  298.082 / 256;
  fRU =  0;
  fGU = -100.291 / 256;
  fBU =  516.411 / 256;
  fRV =  408.583 / 256;
  fGV = -208.120 / 256;
  fBV =  0;

{  // RGB219 ColorFAQ           too dark
  fY  =  256 / 256;
  fRU =  0;
  fGU =  -86.132 / 256;
  fBU =  443.506 / 256;
  fRV =  350.901 / 256;
  fGV = -178.738 / 256;
  fBV =  0; }

{  // Earl            same like RGB255
  fY  =  1.164;
  fRU =  0;
  fGU = -0.392;
  fBU =  2.017;
  fRV =  1.596;
  fGV = -0.813;
  fBV =  0;
}

// |R|   |fY fRU fRV|   |Y|   | 16|
// |G| = |fY fGU fGV| * |U| - |128|
// |B|   |fY fBU fBV|   |V|   |128|

type
  TYUV = packed record
    Y, U, V, F1: Byte;
  end;

  PBGR32 = ^TBGR32;
  TBGR32 = packed record
    B, G, R, A: Byte;
  end;

function YUVtoBGRAPixel(AYUV: DWord): DWord;
var
  ValueY, ValueU, ValueV: Integer;
  ValueB, ValueG, ValueR: Integer;
begin
  ValueY := TYUV(AYUV).Y - 16;
  ValueU := TYUV(AYUV).U - 128;
  ValueV := TYUV(AYUV).V - 128;

  ValueB := Trunc(fY * ValueY + fBU * ValueU);  // fBV = 0
  if ValueB > 255 then
    ValueB := 255;
  if ValueB <   0 then
    ValueB :=   0;

  ValueG := Trunc(fY * ValueY + fGU * ValueU + fGV * ValueV);
  if ValueG > 255 then
    ValueG := 255;
  if ValueG <   0 then
    ValueG :=   0;

  ValueR := Trunc(fY * ValueY + fRV * ValueV);  // fRU = 0
  if ValueR > 255 then
    ValueR := 255;
  if ValueR <   0 then
    ValueR :=   0;

  with TBGR32(Result) do begin
    B := ValueB;
    G := ValueG;
    R := ValueR;
    A := 0;
  end;
end;

type
  TDWordRec = packed record
  case Integer of
    0: (B0, B1, B2, B3: Byte);
    1: (W0, W1: Word);
  end;

// UYVY
// YUV 4:2:2 (Y sample at every pixel, U and V sampled at every second pixel
// horizontally on each line). A macropixel contains 2 pixels in 1 DWord.
// 16 Bits per Pixel, 4 Byte Macropixel
// U0 Y0 V0 Y1
procedure UYVYtoRGB(Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
type
  PUYVY = ^TUYVY;
  TUYVY = packed record
    U, Y0, V, Y1: Byte;
  end;

var
  x, y: Integer;
  w: Integer;
  SrcPtr: PDWord;
  DstPtr: PDWord;
  SrcLineSize: Integer;
  DstLineSize: Integer;
  YUV: DWord;
  b: Byte;
begin
  SrcLineSize := AWidth * 2;
  DstLineSize := AWidth * 4;

  // Dst is Bottom Top Bitmap
  Inc(PByte(Dst), (AHeight - 1) * DstLineSize);

  w := (AWidth div 2) - 1;      { TODO : bei ungeraden Breiten fehlt letztes Pixel }
  for y := 0 to AHeight - 1 do begin
    SrcPtr := Src;
    DstPtr := Dst;
    for x := 0 to w do begin
      YUV := SrcPtr^;
      // First Pixel
      b := TDWordRec(YUV).B0;
      TDWordRec(YUV).B0 := TDWordRec(YUV).B1;
      TDWordRec(YUV).B1 := b;

      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      // Second Pixel
      TDWordRec(YUV).B0 := TDWordRec(YUV).B3;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Inc(SrcPtr);
    end;
    Dec(PByte(Dst), DstLineSize);
    Inc(PByte(Src), SrcLineSize);
  end;
end;

// YUY2, YUNV, V422
// YUV 4:2:2 as for UYVY but with different component ordering within the DWord
// macropixel.
// 16 Bits per Pixel, 4 Byte Macropixel
// Y0 U0 Y1 V0
procedure YUY2toRGB(Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
var
  x, y: Integer;
  w: Integer;
  SrcPtr: PDWord;
  DstPtr: PDWord;
  SrcLineSize: Integer;
  DstLineSize: Integer;
  YUV: DWord;
  b: Byte;
begin
  SrcLineSize := AWidth * 2;
  DstLineSize := AWidth * 4;

  // Dst is Bottom Top Bitmap
  Inc(PByte(Dst), (AHeight - 1) * DstLineSize);

  w := (AWidth div 2) - 1;      { TODO : bei ungeraden Breiten fehlt letztes Pixel }
  for y := 0 to AHeight - 1 do begin
    SrcPtr := Src;
    DstPtr := Dst;
    for x := 0 to w do begin
      YUV := SrcPtr^;
      // First Pixel
      b := TDWordRec(YUV).B2;                  //  Y0 U Y1 V -> Y0 U V Y1
      TDWordRec(YUV).B2 := TDWordRec(YUV).B3;
      TDWordRec(YUV).B3 := b;

      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      // Second Pixel
      TDWordRec(YUV).B0 := TDWordRec(YUV).B3;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Inc(SrcPtr);
    end;
    Dec(PByte(Dst), DstLineSize);
    Inc(PByte(Src), SrcLineSize);
  end;
end;

// BTYUV, I42P
// YUV 4:1:1 (Y sample at every pixel, U and V sampled at every fourth pixel
// horizontally on each line). A macropixel contains 8 pixels in 3 DWords.
// 16 Bits per Pixel, 12 Byte Macropixel
// U0 Y0 V0 Y1 U4 Y2 V4 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6 Y7
procedure BTYUVtoRGB(Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
type
  PBTYUVPixel = ^TBTYUVPixel;
  TBTYUVPixel = packed record
    U0, Y0, V0, Y1, U4, Y2, V4, Y3, Y4, Y5, Y6, Y7: Byte;
  end;

var
  x, y: Integer;
  w: Integer;
  SrcPtr: PBTYUVPixel;
  DstPtr: PDWord;
  SrcLineSize: Integer;
  DstLineSize: Integer;
  YUV: DWord;
  SrcPixel: TBTYUVPixel;
begin
  SrcLineSize := ((AWidth + 7) div 8) * (3 * 4);
  DstLineSize := AWidth * 4;

  w := AWidth - 1;
  for y := 0 to AHeight - 1 do begin
    SrcPtr := Src;
    DstPtr := Dst;
    x := w;
    while x > 0 do begin
      // read macropixel
      SrcPixel := SrcPtr^;
      // First 4 Pixel
      TYUV(YUV).U := SrcPixel.U0;
      TYUV(YUV).V := SrcPixel.V0;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y0;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Dec(x);
      if x <= 0 then
        Break;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y1;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Dec(x);
      if x <= 0 then
        Break;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y2;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Dec(x);
      if x <= 0 then
        Break;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y3;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Dec(x);
      if x <= 0 then
        Break;

      // Second 4 Pixel
      TYUV(YUV).U := SrcPixel.U4;
      TYUV(YUV).V := SrcPixel.V4;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y4;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Dec(x);
      if x <= 0 then
        Break;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y5;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Dec(x);
      if x <= 0 then
        Break;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y6;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Dec(x);
      if x <= 0 then
        Break;

      TYUV(YUV).Y := SrcPixel.Y7;
      DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      Inc(DstPtr);

      Inc(SrcPtr);
    end;
    Inc(PByte(Dst), DstLineSize);
    Inc(PByte(Src), SrcLineSize);
  end;
end;

// YVU9
// 8 bit Y plane followed by 8 bit 4x4 subsampled V and U planes.
// 9 Bits per Pixel, planar format
procedure YVU9toRGB(Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
var
  x, y, r, l: Integer;
  w: Integer;
  SrcYPtr: PByte;
  SrcUPtr: PByte;
  SrcVPtr: PByte;
  DstPtr: PDWord;
  SrcYLineSize: Integer;
  SrcUVLineSize: Integer;
  DstLineSize: Integer;
  YUV: DWord;
begin
  DstLineSize := AWidth * 4;

  SrcYLineSize := AWidth;
  SrcUVLineSize := (AWidth + 3) div 4;

  // Dst is Bottom Top Bitmap
  Inc(PByte(Dst), (AHeight - 1) * DstLineSize);

  SrcYPtr := Src;
  SrcVPtr := PByte(LongInt(SrcYPtr) + SrcYLineSize * AHeight);
  SrcUPtr := PByte(LongInt(SrcVPtr) + SrcUVLineSize * ((AHeight + 3) div 4));

  w := (AWidth div 4) - 1;      { TODO : bei ungeraden Breiten fehlt letztes Pixel }
  for y := 0 to (AHeight div 4) - 1 do begin  { TODO : bei ungeraden H枚hen fehlt letzte Reihe }
    for l := 0 to 3 do begin
      DstPtr := Dst;
      for x := 0 to w do begin
        // U and V
        YUV := (SrcUPtr^ shl 8) or (SrcVPtr^ shl 16);
        for r := 0 to 3 do begin
          YUV := (YUV and $00FFFF00) or SrcYPtr^;
          DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
          Inc(DstPtr);
          Inc(SrcYPtr);
        end;
        Inc(SrcUPtr);
        Inc(SrcVPtr);
      end;
      Dec(PByte(Dst), DstLineSize);
      if l < 3 then begin
        Dec(SrcUPtr, SrcUVLineSize);
        Dec(SrcVPtr, SrcUVLineSize);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

// YUV12, I420, IYUV
// 8 bit Y plane followed by 8 bit 2x2 subsampled U and V planes.
// 12 Bits per Pixel, planar format
procedure YUV12toRGB(Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer);  // I420, IYUV
var
  x, y, l: Integer;
  w: Integer;
  SrcYPtr: PByte;
  SrcUPtr: PByte;
  SrcVPtr: PByte;
  DstPtr: PDWord;
  SrcYLineSize: Integer;
  SrcUVLineSize: Integer;
  DstLineSize: Integer;
  YUV: DWord;
begin
  DstLineSize := AWidth * 4;

  SrcYLineSize := AWidth;
  SrcUVLineSize := (AWidth + 1) div 2;

  // Dst is Bottom Top Bitmap
  Inc(PByte(Dst), (AHeight - 1) * DstLineSize);

  SrcYPtr := Src;
  SrcUPtr := PByte(LongInt(SrcYPtr) + SrcYLineSize * AHeight);
  SrcVPtr := PByte(LongInt(SrcUPtr) + SrcUVLineSize * ((AHeight + 1) div 2));

  w := (AWidth div 2) - 1;      { TODO : bei ungeraden Breiten fehlt letztes Pixel }
  for y := 0 to (AHeight div 2) - 1 do begin  { TODO : bei ungeraden H枚hen fehlt letzte Reihe }
    for l := 0 to 1 do begin
      DstPtr := Dst;
      for x := 0 to w do begin
        // First Pixel
        YUV := SrcYPtr^ or (SrcUPtr^ shl 8) or (SrcVPtr^ shl 16);
        DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
        Inc(DstPtr);
        Inc(SrcYPtr);
        // Second Pixel
        YUV := (YUV and $00FFFF00) or SrcYPtr^;
        DstPtr^ := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
        Inc(DstPtr);
        Inc(SrcYPtr);
        Inc(SrcUPtr);
        Inc(SrcVPtr);
      end;
      Dec(PByte(Dst), DstLineSize);
      if l = 0 then begin
        Dec(SrcUPtr, SrcUVLineSize);
        Dec(SrcVPtr, SrcUVLineSize);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

// Y8, Y800
// Simple, single Y plane for monochrome images.
// 8 Bits per Pixel, planar format
procedure Y8toRGB(Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
var
  x, y: Integer;
  w: Integer;
  SrcPtr: PByte;
  DstPtr: PDWord;
  SrcLineSize: Integer;
  DstLineSize: Integer;
  Pixel: DWord;
begin
  SrcLineSize := AWidth;
  DstLineSize := AWidth * 4;

  // Dst is Bottom Top Bitmap
  Inc(PByte(Dst), (AHeight - 1) * DstLineSize);

  w := (AWidth) - 1;
  for y := 0 to AHeight - 1 do begin
    SrcPtr := Src;
    DstPtr := Dst;
    for x := 0 to w do begin
      Pixel := SrcPtr^;
      TDWordRec(Pixel).B1 := TDWordRec(Pixel).B0;
      TDWordRec(Pixel).B2 := TDWordRec(Pixel).B0;
      TDWordRec(Pixel).B3 := 0;
      DstPtr^ := Pixel;
      Inc(DstPtr);
      Inc(SrcPtr);
    end;
    Dec(PByte(Dst), DstLineSize);
    Inc(PByte(Src), SrcLineSize);
  end;
end;

// Y211
// Packed YUV format with Y sampled at every second pixel across each line
// and U and V sampled at every fourth pixel.
// 8 Bits per Pixel, 4 Byte Macropixel
// Y0, U0, Y2, V0
procedure Y211toRGB(Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
type
  PYUYV = ^TYUYV;
  TYUYV = packed record
    Y0, U, Y2, V: Byte;
  end;

var
  x, y: Integer;
  w : Integer;
  SrcPtr : PDWord;
  DstPtr : PDWord;
  SrcLineSize : Integer;
  DstLineSize : Integer;
  YUV: DWord;
  BGR: DWord;
  b: Byte;
begin
  SrcLineSize := ((AWidth + 3) div 4) * 4;
  DstLineSize := AWidth * 4;

  // Dst is Bottom Top Bitmap
  Inc(PByte(Dst), (AHeight - 1) * DstLineSize);

  w := (AWidth div 4) - 1;      { TODO : bei ungeraden Breiten fehlt letztes Pixel }
  for y := 0 to AHeight - 1 do begin
    SrcPtr := Src;
    DstPtr := Dst;
    for x := 0 to w do begin
      // Y0 U Y2 V
      YUV := SrcPtr^;
      // First and second Pixel
      b := TDWordRec(YUV).B2;                   // Y0 U Y2 V -> Y0 U V Y2
      TDWordRec(YUV).B2 := TDWordRec(YUV).B3;
      TDWordRec(YUV).B3 := b;
      BGR := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      DstPtr^ := BGR;
      Inc(DstPtr);
      DstPtr^ := BGR;
      Inc(DstPtr);

      // third and fourth
      TDWordRec(YUV).B0 := TDWordRec(YUV).B3;   // Y0 U V Y2 -> Y2 U V Y2
      BGR := YUVtoBGRAPixel(YUV);
      DstPtr^ := BGR;
      Inc(DstPtr);
      DstPtr^ := BGR;
      Inc(DstPtr);

      Inc(SrcPtr);
    end;
    Dec(PByte(Dst), DstLineSize);
    Inc(PByte(Src), SrcLineSize);
  end;
end;

function ConvertCodecToRGB(Codec: TVideoCodec; Src, Dst: Pointer; AWidth, AHeight: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  case Codec of
    vcYUY2:  YUY2toRGB (Src, Dst, AWidth, AHeight);
    vcUYVY:  UYVYtoRGB (Src, Dst, AWidth, AHeight);
    vcBTYUV: BTYUVtoRGB(Src, Dst, AWidth, AHeight);
    vcYVU9:  YVU9toRGB (Src, Dst, AWidth, AHeight);
    vcYUV12: YUV12toRGB(Src, Dst, AWidth, AHeight);
    vcY8:    Y8toRGB   (Src, Dst, AWidth, AHeight);
    vcY211:  Y211toRGB (Src, Dst, AWidth, AHeight);
  else
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

//  History:
//  2005-02-12, Peter J. Haas
//
//  2002-02-22, Peter J. Haas
//   - add YVU9, YUV12 (I420)
//   - add Y211 (untested)
//
//  2001-06-14, Peter J. Haas
//   - First public version
//   - YUY2, UYVY, BTYUV (Y41P), Y8

end.
```

Some message results:

```
var
    MsgResult : Integer ;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var  BitmapInfo: TBitmapInfo;

begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;

  FBitmap:= TBitmap.Create;
  FBitmap.Width:= PICWIDTH;
  FBitmap.Height:= PICHEIGHT+ SUBLINEHEIGHT+ EXTRAHEIGHT;
  FBitmap.PixelFormat:= pf32Bit;
  FBitmap.Canvas.Font.Assign(Panel1.Font);
  FBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bssolid;
  FBitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(0, PICHEIGHT, PICWIDTH, PICHEIGHT+ SUBLINEHEIGHT);

  FJpeg:= TJpegImage.Create;

  FCapHandle:= capCreateCaptureWindow('Video', WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, PICWIDTH, PICHEIGHT, Panel1.Handle, 1);   // returns 2558326
  MsgResult := SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0);                                                   // returns 0
  MsgResult := SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 15000, 0);                                              // returns 1
  MsgResult := sendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_OVERLAY, 1, 0);                                                      // returns 0
  MsgResult := SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, 1, 0);                                                      // returns 0

  // SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT,1,0);     // -this was commented out

  FillChar(BitmapInfo, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), 0);
  MsgResult := SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), Integer(@BitmapInfo));              // returns 0
  FCodec:= BICompressionToVideoCodec(bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biCompression);                                              // returns vcRGB
  if FCodec<> vcUnknown then begin
    Timer1.Enabled:= true;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBitmap.Free;
  FJpeg.Free;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FCodec= vcUnknown then
    showMessage('unknown compression');
  FBitmap.Height:= PICHEIGHT+ SUBLINEHEIGHT;
end;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
MsgResult := SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME, 0, integer(@FrameCallbackFunction));         // returns 0
MsgResult := SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOP, 1, 0); // ist hintergrundlauff盲hig            // returns 0
end;
```

Comment: Are any of the WM_CAP... messages returning errors?

Comment: Hi Remy,  see my edits to the question - message results are comments out to the right. Thanks. R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your program works for me on Win7 32bits with D2010**.

What it does though is raising an exception:

```
---------------------------
Project WebCamTest.exe raised exception class EFCreateError with message 
'Cannot create file "c:\webcam.jpg". Access is denied'.
---------------------------
```

which can be corrected by changing

```
FJpeg.SaveToFile('c:\webcam.jpg');
```

to

```
FJpeg.SaveToFile(TPath.GetTempPath + '\webcam.jpg');
```

And also, it does not display the whole available image, you'd have to enlarge your Panel, recenter or shrink the webcam output.

**Update with some code modifications that would make it work per your comments...**

```
  // introducing the RGB array and a buffer
  TVideoArray = array[1..PICHEIGHT] of array[1..PICWIDTH] of TRGBTriple;
  PVideoArray = ^TVideoArray;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
[...]
  FBuf24_1: TVideoArray;
[...]

function FrameCallbackFunction(AHandle: hWnd; VIDEOHDR: TVideoHDRPtr): bool; stdcall;
var
  I: integer;
begin
  result:= true;

  with form1 do begin
  try
    if ConvertCodecToRGB(FCodec, VideoHDR^.lpData, @FBuf2, PICWIDTH, PICHEIGHT) then
    begin
      for I:= 1 to PICHEIGHT do FBuf1[I]:= FBuf2[PICHEIGHT- (I- 1)];
      SetBitmapBits(FBitmap.Handle, PICWIDTH* PICHEIGHT* SizeOf(DWord), @FBuf1);
    end
    else
    begin  // assume RGB
      for I:= 1 to PICHEIGHT do
        FBuf24_1[I] := PVideoArray(VideoHDR^.lpData)^[PICHEIGHT-I+1];
      SetBitmapBits(FBitmap.Handle, PICWIDTH* PICHEIGHT* SizeOf(RGBTriple), @FBuf24_1);
    end;
[...]
```

Comment: On my system, the message results I get are:

    WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECTMsgResult     = false 
    WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATEMsgResult    = true  
    WM_CAP_SET_OVERLAYMsgResult        = false 
    WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWMsgResult        = false 
    WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAMEMsgResult = true  
    WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOPMsgResult  = false 

and FrameCallbackFunction never fires.  It looks as if it is failing to connect.

Comment: Clearly you cannot connect to the webcam. 
Have you tried with a capture driver other than 0? It can be from 0 to 9. Maybe you have more than 1 and the webcam is not the index 0?
`MsgResult := SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, x, 0);`

Comment: Thanks François.  At present I don't have any webcams - just a simulator.  The simulator seems to go in that Skype can see the "camera" OK.  I tried calling SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, x, 0); with x = 0 through 9 and they all returned false.  Incidentally - how were you able to format the text as code in the comment?

Comment: Update - I installed a real webcam.  Now, when I execute the SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0) ; a dialog pops up asking me to select the video capture source.  The drop-down only has one entry in it - for the Logitech webcam.  When I select this however, I still get the same failure result (false) from SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0) ;.

Comment: Hey François,  I am tantalizingly close.  With a real webcam connected, I can get 1 second snapshots displaying on the panel.  Problem is, I need programmatic access to the image.  The JPEG file saved is all black.  I have tried several other variants of the example code off the web and they all work, but the jpeg is blank.  Any ideas?

Comment: Time to learn some debugging... ;-) Your function `ConvertCodecToRGB` returns a `Boolean` status if it converted OK or not. You should test it. You'd find it failed because the Codec it is passed (probably in your case also) is a `vcRGB` which falls in the `case else` where nothing is done. And BTW to embed code in comments, use the back quote `\``

Comment: Correct.  So "vcRGB" is returned by the routine BICompressionToVideoCodec.  How should I handle that case value?

Comment: I'm really not familiar with all that, but I guess that in this case you might not need to convert the pixels format, just have to pass them in the proper order to the destination...

Comment: I found this comment: 

`"The problem with all black or white images comes from the fact that ConvertCodecToRGB doesn't handle case where the codec is running in RGB (vcRGB) mode.  In this case you need to change the bitmap from 32 to 24 bit mode and copy the data from the source buffer to the dest buffer unchanged.  Remember that the MOVE in Delphi is limited to an INTEGER for the move size."

which does suggest something along the lines of what you are suggesting.  I'm not sure how the data is arranged in the buffer - the size is reported as 304128 (=640x480) suggesting one byte per pixel?

Comment: Aha. 640x480 is not 304128.  Close but not close enough.  The structure BitmapInfo after the call to SendMessage(FCapHandle, WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), Integer(@BitmapInfo)) has the values Width=352, Height=288, BitCount=24, so I conclude it's 3 bytes per pixel: 352x288x3 = 304128.  Now presumably I need to get this data into the destination buffer?

Comment: That would make sense for RGB: 3 bytes, 1 per color, total 24 bits. Now you have to find in what order they come and where to put them in the dest buffer.

Comment: See my update. These code changes do the trick... And for me it works with 640x480 BTW.

Comment: Brilliant.  I'd almost got to the same point (my image is still upside down!).  Many thanks, R.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use DirectX API instead of deprecated Video For Windows (VFW) API:
http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample

Here is a link to a larger project implementing the code detailed below:
http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicssnippets/delphiwebcamcaptureexample

Interchange lines indicated by comment notation as you wish.

```
program WebcamTest;
//www.delphibasics.info
//cswi

uses
  Windows;

const
  WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = 1034;
  WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME = 1084;
  //WM_CAP_SAVEDIB = 1049;
  WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY = 1054;//
  WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = 1035;

function SendMessageA(hWnd: Integer;
                      Msg: Integer;
                      wParam: Integer;
                      lParam: Integer): Integer;
                      stdcall;
                      external 'user32.dll' name 'SendMessageA';

function capGetDriverDescriptionA(DrvIndex: Cardinal;
                                  Name: PAnsiChar;
                                  NameLen: Integer;
                                  Description: PAnsiChar;
                                  DescLen: Integer) : Boolean;
                                  stdcall;
                                external 'avicap32.dll' name 'capGetDriverDescriptionA';

function capCreateCaptureWindowA(lpszWindowName: PAnsiChar;
                                 dwStyle: Integer;
                                 x : Integer;
                                 y : Integer;
                                 nWidth : Integer;
                                 nHeight : Integer;
                                 ParentWin: Integer;
                                 nId: Integer): Integer;
                                 stdcall;
                                 external 'avicap32.dll' name 'capCreateCaptureWindowA';

function IntToStr(i: Integer): String;
begin
  Str(i, Result);
end;

var
  WebCamId : Integer;
  CaptureWindow : Integer;
  x : Integer;
  FileName : PAnsiChar;
  hData:  DWORD;
  pData:  Pointer;
  dwSize: DWORD;
  szText : AnsiString;
  FileHandle, BytesWritten : LongWord;
begin
  WebcamId := 0;
  CaptureWindow := capCreateCaptureWindowA('CaptureWindow', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  if CaptureWindow <> 0 then
  begin
    if SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, WebCamId, 0) <> 1 then
    begin
      SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
    end
    else
    begin
      for x := 1 to 20 do // Take 20 photos.
      begin
        SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME, 0, 0);
        FileName := PAnsiChar('C:\Test' + IntToStr(x) + '.bmp');
        //SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, LongInt(FileName));
        SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, LongInt(FileName));//
        if OpenClipBoard(0) then
        begin
          hData := GetClipBoardData(CF_DIB);
          if hData <> 0 then
          begin
            pData := GlobalLock(hData);
            if pData <> nil then
            begin
              dwSize := GlobalSize(hData);
              if dwSize <> 0 then
              begin
                FileHandle := CreateFileA(FileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, 0);
                WriteFile(FileHandle, pData, dwSize, BytesWritten, nil);
                CloseHandle(FileHandle);
              end;
              GlobalUnlock(DWORD(pData));
            end;
          end;
          CloseClipBoard;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    SendMessageA(CaptureWindow, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks Danny.  Those links look like there is some good stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

I use a component called TVideoCap.  It is for 3, 4, and 5 but it includes source so it is easy to update.  It will do exactly what you want.  Just do a search for 'TVideoCap'.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.  Do you have any EXE that you have produced using this unit that you can give me that works - I just want to verify that there is nothing inherently wrong with my system.  R

Comment: Hi David,  I downloaded VideoCap and installed a real Webcam - my results are the same as in the previous answer above - now that I have a real webcam, then I try to connect to a driver the dialog opens asking me to select the source, but the connect fails anyway