# Delphi + webcam

Tags: delphi, directdraw

I am looking for a way to use my webcam in delphi, primary for grabbing a picture, by some reason I cannot use TWAIN drivers.

Comment: See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454688/getting-a-snapshot-from-a-webcam-with-delphi) and [my answer with some working code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454688/getting-a-snapshot-from-a-webcam-with-delphi/3455652#3455652). See if it works for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these resources

[DSPack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dspack/)

> DSPack is a set of Components and class to write Multimedia Applications using MS Direct Show and DirectX technologies. DSPack 2.3 is designed to work with DirectX 9 on Win9X, ME, 2000, and Windows XP operating systems using Delphi 5,6,7 and BCB6.

or

[capCreateCaptureWindow function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756879%28VS.85%29.aspx)   <sup>([sample code](http://www.portugal-a-programar.org/forum/index.php/topic,4474.msg284375.html?PHPSESSID=7b25d5cf0cd5fcc39043d8c65741d077#msg284375))</sup>

> The capCreateCaptureWindow function creates a capture window.
>
> *Syntax
> C++*
>
> ```
> HWND VFWAPI capCreateCaptureWindow(
>   LPCTSTR lpszWindowName,
>   DWORD dwStyle,
>   int x,
>   int y,
>   int nWidth,
>   int nHeight,
>   HWND hWnd,
>   int nID
> );
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I was typing this in a comment to Trinidad's answer, but the message became to long.

2 years ago I've tried *all* of the Delphi solutions that I could find to grab video.

My requirements were:

- Needs to be free (as in beer), (or *very* cheap + easy payment method)
- Needs to be stable
- Needs to be easy to use
- Needs to have sufficient example code
- Needs to work in Delphi 2009/2010

To tell the truth, the overall results were disappointing. None of the solutions met all of the above the requirements.

**DsPack** scored the best on all points, but I could only make it work in Delphi7, until I found an "unofficial" port on this page: http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/

Nowadays it works like a charm, in Delphi 2010.

<sub>I'm a very happy user, so let me take this opportunity to thank the creators of dsPack and Sebastian Zierer who ported the code to the modern Delphi's!</sub>